# Can't override Magento Adminhtml Block

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, blocks, overrides

## Sysnopsis

I am trying to change a tab on the admin products page (grouped); However for some obscure reason I cannot get my module to work.  The problem seems to be my module is completely ignored.

## Code

**app/etc/modules/Vendor_Catalog.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vendor_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Catalog/etc/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Catalog>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <vendor_catalog>
                <class>Vendor_Catalog_Block</class>
            </vendor_catalog>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>        
                    <catalog_product_edit_tabs_grouped>Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Grouped</catalog_product_edit_tabs_grouped>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Vendor/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs/Grouped.php**:

```
<?php
class Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Grouped
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs
{
}
```

Comment: remove grouped form your tab and try below one because you have to directory structure same  path as overridden block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During my sleep I must have subconsciously thought of the solution; it would appear that I was overriding the *wrong* block for this scenario.

Also it appears to me that `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Grouped` is either deprecated or just not used any more.

Nevertheless I added a `die;` statement inside the cores' `protected function _prepareLayout()` method - lo and behold nothing stopped processing.  So I consult my best friend `grep` and found the following:

```
$ grep -r -e 'Associated Products' "app/code/core/Mage/"
```

A core block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group` which I then decided to override - this worked (source attached for anyone else that has this problem).

---

**Vendor/Catalog/etc/config.xml**:

```
<config>

    ...

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <vendor_catalog>
                <class>Vendor_Catalog_Block</class>
            </vendor_catalog>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group>Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group</catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    ...

</config>
```

**Vendor/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Group.php**:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group
{
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        // Override the tab Url with my controller/action.
        return $this->getUrl('*/vendor_catalog_product/superGroup', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Block as per Below code

```
...

<global>
    <blocks>
        <vendor_catalog>
            <class>Vendor_Catalog_Block</class>
        </vendor_catalog>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group>Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group</catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>

...
```

And the File structure like as below path

\app\code\local\Vendor\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tabs.php

```
<?php
class Vendor_Catalog_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Group
{
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
    // Override the tab Url with my controller/action.
        return $this->getUrl('*/vendor_catalog_product/superGroup', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work because `<catalog>` is not my module.  Also I do not want to extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs` But override  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs_Grouped` which so happens to extend the former.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12634/takingsides

join this room

Comment: we will discuss on chat.